# Problems with "cabal install cabal-install" in Windows

Tags: cabal, cabal-install

After Haskell Plaftform 2013.2.0.0 installation, the cabal.exe is in "C:\Program Files (x86)\HaskellPlatform\2013.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\"

After execution of "cabal install cabal-install" the updated cabal.exe file is in "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin"

**But the old cabal.exe is still in "..\extralibs", so it is always the old version to be performed.**

User variables for Alberto: PATH = C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin

System variables: Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin

**I hastily solved this problem by deleting the cabal.exe file in "..\extralibs", but I do not think that this is the best solution.**

I have found this problem even on other computers with Windows operating systems (Vista, Windows 7,  Windows 8)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify where to install cabal with the "--bindir=" option. So if you do the following, it should find it (You may have to run it from an administrative command prompt):

```
cabal install --bindir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\bin" cabal-install
```

The Haskell\bin directory didn't exist on my install (Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0 on Windows 8 64-bit), but the install still put it first in the path. So I assumed that is where it expected cabal to install. Doing so will make sure it is found first. You can check with `where cabal`. It will list all cabal's on the path, with the first one used by default.